# Why won't my modelform save to the database once I change the form field from CharField to ModelChoiceField?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Folks - first time question-asker here, although I've relied on Stackoverflow for years as a reference tool.  Any and all feedback appreciated.  Here's my issue:

I'm building a Django app that takes data in through a ModelForm, saves it to the underlying model, then runs a database operation based on the updated model.

This seemed to be working alright when my ModelForm consisted of a CharField. However, once I changed the form field to ModelChoiceField so that inputs on the page are selected from a drop-down, it looks like data is no longer saving to the database upon Submit. Running the app does not kick up any error codes, and I've confirmed by directly querying the db using dbshell that the Menu table referenced in code below is in fact empty.

Any thoughts?  I've done a pretty robust search on existing questions (although maybe somebody can prove me wrong) and can't find anything directly pertaining to this issue. Relevant code snippets follow:

**forms.py**

```
class MenuForm(forms.ModelForm):
recipe_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Recipe', empty_label = 'Choose from the dropdown', queryset = Recipes.objects.values_list('recipe_name', flat = 'True').order_by('recipe_name'))
class Meta:
    model = Menu
    fields = ('recipe_name',)
```

**views.py**

```
def set_menu(request):
Menu.objects.all().delete()
MenuFormSet = modelformset_factory(Menu, form = MenuForm, extra = 7)
context = RequestContext(request)
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = MenuFormSet(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
        return populate_grocerylist(request)
    else:
        message = "Something went wrong"
        return render_to_response('menu.html', {'message': message}, context)
else:
    formset = MenuFormSet()
    return render_to_response('menu.html', {'formset': MenuFormSet()}, context)
```

Comment: Why don't you put the actual invalid formset in the context dict, like the documentation says, so you can see exactly why it is invalid? Plus, on successful submit, you *must* redirect, not just return the value of another view.

Comment: Any particular reason that you are deleting all `Menu` objects at the beginning?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - I believe that the formset is valid since clicking the Submit button does not return the "Something went wrong" error which fires in the event that formset.is_valid() returns False.

Comment: @RahulGupta - I am deleting all Menu objects at the beginning of set_menu because I want the Menu model to be cleared and repopulated each time the application is used.